# Why does Hanson-Wright inequality give a poor bound in this example?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

The following is from High-Dimensional Probability by Roman Vershyni

> (Hanson-Wright inequality) Let $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with independent, zero-mean, and sub-Gaussian coordinates. Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Then, for every $t\geq 0$, we have
>   $$P(|X^\intercal A X - E[X^\intercal A X ]| \geq t) \leq 2 \exp \Big[ -c \min (\frac{t^2}{K^4 \|A\|_F^2}, \frac{t}{K^2 \|A\|_2})\Big],$$
>   where $K = \max_i \|X_i\|_{\psi_2}$.

I give an example where this bound is quite poor. Suppose that $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $X_i$ are i.i.d. standard Gaussian. For any vector $X$ it is trivial that $P(X^\intercal A X \leq 0) = 0$. I apply Hanson-Wright to this probability:

\begin{align}
P(X^\intercal A X \leq 0) = P(- X^\intercal A X + E[X^\intercal A X] \geq  E[X^\intercal A X]) = P(- X^\intercal A X + E[X^\intercal A X] \geq  \text{tr}(A)])
\end{align}

Hanson-Wright gives the following bound
\begin{align}
P(- X^\intercal A X + E[X^\intercal A X] \geq  \text{tr}(A)]) \leq \Big[ -c \min (\frac{\text{tr}(A)^2}{K^4 \|A\|_F^2}, \frac{\text{tr}(A)}{K^2 \|A\|_2})\Big]
\end{align}

Now, this bound is poor when $A$ is not well-conditioned, even though the correct probability is zero. For example, if eigenvalues of $A$ are $(1, \epsilon/(n-1), \dots, \epsilon/(n-1))$, then

$$\frac{\text{tr}(A)}{\|A\|_2} = 1+\epsilon.$$

Why does this bound poor in this example? Simulations show that this is also true when $A$ is nearly positive definite (e.g. $A = B^\intercal B - \epsilon x x^\intercal$).

Answer (score 1):

For the lower tail that you are interested in, there is a sharper bound:
$P(X^TAX  - trace[A] < - 2 t ) \le e^{ - t^2/\|A\|_F^2}$.
If you take $t$ of order $trace[A]$ you obtain something more reasonable.

See Equation (4.2) in Laurent and Massart (2000.